# How to split a string before a specific character (so that the delimiter character is in the second part of the result)

Tags: java, arrays, string, split

if I have

```
String a = "abc,,,";
```

what should I do to get

```
result[0].equals("abc");
result[1].equals(",,,");
```

Comment: you can split in the middle of the string

Comment: Define place you want to split. What is so *regular* about it?

Comment: `"abc,,,".split("(?=,)", 2)` gives you `"abc"` and `",,,"`.

Comment: and what if the String is ("abc,?/").......and i need 2 diff strings "abc" and ",?/" @aioobe

Comment: The same approach works. `(?=,)` is a regular expression that means "right before `,`" so `"abc,?/".split("(?=,)", 2)` will give you `"abc"` and `",?/"`. Give it a try.

Comment: If your input is `a,b,,c,,,d,,,,e,,,,,f,,,,,,`, what do you want the split result to be? Please update question to specify full rule set.

Comment: yaa u r right @FrankPuffer.......do you have any answer Sir?

Comment: There is no such case @Andreas

Comment: Ok..... thank you @aioobe

Comment: @aioobe what if the specific character can range between numbers and still i need to spilt it before the number eg ;- String a="abc123" & String b="abc234" i need only 'abc' from both the strings

Answer (score 1):

The most elementary way is this:

```
final int pos = a.indexOf(',');
if( pos == -1 ) { // character not found, handle this case somehow }
String [] result = new String [2];
result[0]=a.substring(0, pos);
result[1]=a.substring(pos);
```

Comment: You can combine the last 3 lines as `String[] result = { a.substring(0, pos), a.substring(pos) };`

Comment: Excellent answer. Split using regex can do it, but in this case, it's not the best tool for the job.